# Navigation using $stateProvider and ion-side-menu not working in ionic framework

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I used the ionic CLI to create an application.

- ionic start myApp sidemenu
- ionic platform add ios
- ionic build ios
- ionic emulate ios

I then proceeded to modify app.js to look like the following.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app', 
    abstract: true, 
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html', 
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.register', {
    url: '/register',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.snap', {
    url: '/snap',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/snap.html',
        controller: 'SnapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.search', {
    url: '/search', 
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.browse', {
    url: '/browse', 
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html',
        controller: 'BrowseCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/snap');
});
```

I've modified controller.js to look like the following.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
  $scope.loginData = {};
  $ionicModal
    .fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', { scope: $scope })
    .then(function(modal) { $scope.modal = modal; });
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})
.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope) {
  //TODO
})
.controller('SnapCtrl', function($scope, Camera) {
  //TODO
})
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope) {
 //TODO
})
.controller('BrowseCtrl', function($scope) {
 //TODO
});
```

The services.js was modified as follows (mostly taken from http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/).

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {
  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();
      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);
      return q.promoise;
    }
  }
}]);
```

My menu.html was modified as follows.

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">MyMenu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
          <i class="icon ion-person"></i> Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/register">
          <i class="icon ion-person-add"></i> Register
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/snap">
          <i class="icon ion-camera"></i> Snap
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          <i class="icon ion-search"></i> Search
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          <i class="icon ion-android-document"></i> Browse
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

When I run this in the iOS emulator, clicking on the login links menu item work (a modal shows up) always. However, clicking on the any other menu item only works for the first menu item clicked. For example, if I click register, then the register page shows up, but then clicking any other menu item doesn't work (the register page continues to show up). This behavior also shows up on the android emulator (`ionic  emulate android`) and also the browser (`ionic serve`).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what is `Camera` in `.controller('SnapCtrl', function($scope, Camera) {...`, check it is defined or not..?

Comment: It is defined in services.js (just posted).

Comment: @JaneWayne try to create a Plunkr so that easy for us to find the problem

Comment: I forgot to wire in my services. `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])` needs to be `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])`. Sorry.

Comment: try `href="#/register"` in your state url its looking for `url: '/register',`

Comment: Hi @JaneWayne is this issue resolved? I am stuck with the same problem